# How to get a child key value in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with Firebase and I'm currently using JavaScript SDK to integrate my web application with Firebase.

My question is: **How to get value within the red box that I drew on the image?**

I am using

```
snapshot.key
```

to access the key valuebut it returns the generated key (blue box) to me which is not the one I wanted.

[image: Database structure]

Comment: Show us some code first :)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: var dbRecording = firebase.database().ref("recordings/");
        dbRecording.once("value", function(snapshot2) {
            if (snapshot2.exists()) {
                snapshot2.forEach(function(value) {
                    var childKey = value.key;
                    console.log(childKey);
                });
            }
        });

Comment: this is my code

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, I already tried the code from the link you given, but it still shows the generated key

Comment: Instead of using the `key` property, use the `val()` method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec if i used val(), it will get the value of speechtext, but what I want is i want to get the "Speechtext".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it is not 100% clear what you are looking for. If you know that you have a sub-node with the key `speechtext` under the `recording` parent node with key `LRC2o....` you don't need to query for getting the key of this sub-node (since you know it).

If, on the other hand, you want to iterate on all the keys of the sub-nodes of the `recording` node, do as follows (based on your code):

```
var dbRecording = firebase.database().ref("recordings/"); 
dbRecording.once("value", function(snapshot2) { 
  if (snapshot2.exists()) { 
    snapshot2.forEach(function(value) { 
      var childObject = value.val(); 

      Object.keys(childObject).forEach(e => console.log(`key = ${e}`));

    }); 
  } 
});
```

If you want the keys and the values, do as follows:

```
var dbRecording = firebase.database().ref("recordings/"); 
dbRecording.once("value", function(snapshot2) { 
  if (snapshot2.exists()) { 
    snapshot2.forEach(function(value) { 
      var childObject = value.val(); 

      Object.keys(childObject).forEach(e => console.log(`key = ${e}  value = ${childObject[e]}`));

    }); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. :)